# How to show $E(XE(Y\mid F)=E(E(X\mid F)Y)$?

Tags: conditional-expectation

Let $X,Y\in\mathcal{L}^2$ and let $F$ be a $\sigma$-algebra.

How to show that $E(XE(Y\mid F)=E(E(X\mid F)Y)$?

Maybe you can give me some help?

Comment: It's more conventional to use $\mathscr{F}$ to denote a general $\sigma$-algebra. "$F$" may be confused with the random variable named $F$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is iterated expectation.
$$
E[XE(Y\mid F)]=E[E(XE(Y\mid F)\mid F)]=E[E(Y\mid F)E(X\mid F)]
$$
where the second equality is because $E(Y\mid F)$ is $F$-measurable. Now can you do the same with $E[E(X\mid F)Y]$ to produce the rightmost expression above?

Comment: $E(E(X|F)Y)=E(E(E(X|F)Y|F))=E(E(X|F)E(Y|F))$?

Comment: @Rhjg Yes, that's right.